# How to send an image with this customized C# Mail function?

Tags: c#, image

I am a new C# developer and trying to include an image in the text mail that my system is sending it using Mail function. Everything works fine except when I added the following bunch of code to my code:

```
string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\";
                string fileName = imagePath + "EmailNotification.jpg";
                AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text)
                LinkedResource linkedRes = new LinkedResource(fileName);
                linkedRes.ContentId = "image1";
                linkedRes.ContentType.Name = fileName;
                av.LinkedResources.Add(linkedRes);
```

It gave me a red line under the following line:

```
    AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text)



C# Mail Function:

    /*For sending an email notification to the new user*/
        protected void SendNotificationByEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
        {
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MailServer");
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("Test@MailServer.com", "Test System)");


                msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
                msg.Subject = MailSubject;
                msg.Body = MessageBody;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
                sc.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        protected void Send(string username)
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";

            string networkID = username.ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(2000);

                //initiate the varibles 
                string name = null;

                // Open DB connection.
                conn.Open();

                string cmdText2 = @"SELECT     Name
                                    FROM       dbo.employee
                                    WHERE     (Username = @networkID)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@networkID", networkID);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                            sbEmailAddresses.Append(username).Append("@mailServer.com");
                        }
                    }

                    //var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();
                    string body = @"Good day "
                                    + name +
                                    @", <br /><br />
                                    You have been added to the <a href='http://localhost/TestSys'>Test</a>. 
                                    <br /><br />
resources. 
                                    </b> <br /> <br />
                                    <img src='images/Admin/EmailNotification.jpg' alt=' Message'/>

                    string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\";
                    string fileName = imagePath + "EmailNotification.jpg";
                    AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text)
                    LinkedResource linkedRes = new LinkedResource(fileName);
                    linkedRes.ContentId = "image1";
                    linkedRes.ContentType.Name = fileName;
                    av.LinkedResources.Add(linkedRes);

                    SendNotificationByEmail(sbEmailAddresses.ToString(), "", "Welcome", body, true);
                    sbEmailAddresses.Clear();
                    reader.Close();


                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

**So how to fix that to be able to send an image with my text mail?**

Answer (score 3):

```
AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
  body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text);
```

You have to just write `Html` after the `MediaTypeNames`. Like this.

```
AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
  body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
```